# Polynomial Curve fittings with GNU Scientific Library (GSL)

Tags: python, c++, numpy, polynomial-math, gsl

I'm going to use GNU Scientific Library (GSL) for solving Polynomial Curve fittings. Here is my function for polyFit - see **"C++ code"**. If I use below example data, then I got the result below - see **"Output"**. I've tried to verification if it is OK or not with python - see **"Python Code"** and **Python Output**. I don't know why GSL and Python result is different. The trend of Python result is similar with original data. However, GSL result is different. Why it is different ? It would be very helpful if Somebody help me.

**Output :**

```
> Polynomial Curve Fittings : order = 6 th, Data Size =  200
> best fit: Y = 840810 + 2354.69 X + 1.66468 X^2 + -0.000321755 X^3 + -3.53193e- 007 X^4 + 1.06755e-010 X^5 + -8.11813e-015 X^6    
> chisq = 4.76957e+008
```

**C++ Code :**

```
    struct LensTiltMap{
        double xPos;    
        double yPos1;

        double yCompPos1;
    };

    std::vector<LensTiltMap> polyFit(std::vector<LensTiltMap> _vecData)
    {
        std::vector<LensTiltMap> _vec;

        if (_vecData.size() != 0)
        {
            double* data_x = &_vecData[0].xPos;
            double* data_y = &_vecData[0].yPos1;
            int n = _vecData.size();
            int order = 6;
            double chisq;

            gsl_vector *y, *c;
            gsl_matrix *X, *cov;

            y = gsl_vector_alloc(n);
            c = gsl_vector_alloc(order + 1);
            X = gsl_matrix_alloc(n, order + 1);
            cov = gsl_matrix_alloc(order + 1, order + 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < order + 1; j++) {
                    gsl_matrix_set(X, i, j, pow(data_x[i], j));
                }
                gsl_vector_set(y, i, data_y[i]);
            }

            gsl_multifit_linear_workspace * work = gsl_multifit_linear_alloc(n, order + 1);
            gsl_multifit_linear(X, y, c, cov, &chisq, work);
            gsl_multifit_linear_free(work);

            std::vector<double> vc;
            for (int i = 0; i < order + 1; i++) {
                vc.push_back(gsl_vector_get(c, i));
            }

            cout << "# Polynomial Curve Fittings : order = " << order << " th, Data Size =  " << n << endl;

            cout << "# best fit: Y = " << vc[0] << " + " << vc[1] << " X + " << vc[2] << " X^2 + " << vc[3] << " X^3 + " << vc[4] << " X^4 + " << vc[5] << " X^5 + " << vc[6] << " X^6 " << endl;

            cout << "# covariance matrix = \n"
                << "[" << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (0), (0)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (0), (1)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (0), (2)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (0), (3)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (0), (4)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (0), (5)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (0), (6))
                << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (1), (0)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (1), (1)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (1), (2)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (1), (3)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (1), (4)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (1), (5)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (1), (6))
                << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (2), (0)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (2), (1)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (2), (2)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (2), (3)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (2), (4)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (2), (5)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (2), (6))
                << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (3), (0)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (3), (1)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (3), (2)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (3), (3)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (3), (4)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (3), (5)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (3), (6))
                << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (4), (0)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (4), (1)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (4), (2)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (4), (3)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (4), (4)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (4), (5)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (4), (6))
                << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (5), (0)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (5), (1)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (5), (2)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (5), (3)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (5), (4)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (5), (5)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (5), (6))
                << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (6), (0)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (6), (1)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (6), (2)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (6), (3)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (6), (4)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (6), (5)) << ", " << gsl_matrix_get(cov, (6), (6))
                << "]" << endl;

            cout << "# chisq = " << chisq << endl;

            gsl_vector_free(y);
            gsl_vector_free(c);
            gsl_matrix_free(X);
            gsl_matrix_free(cov);

            for (std::vector<LensTiltMap>::iterator it = _vecData.begin(); it != _vecData.end(); ++it) {
                LensTiltMap _data = *it;

                _data.yCompPos1 = vc[6] + vc[5] * pow(_data.xPos, 1) + vc[4] * pow(_data.xPos, 2) + vc[3] * pow(_data.xPos, 3) + vc[2] * pow(_data.xPos, 4) + vc[1] * pow(_data.xPos, 5) + vc[0] * pow(_data.xPos, 6);

                _vec.push_back(_data);
            }
        }
        else
            return _vecData;

        return _vec.size() != 0 ? _vec : _vecData;
    }
```

**Python Code :**

See below example data with python. I use the example below link.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-1000,1000,10)
y = np.array([ 5347.21,  5338.78,  5365.01,  5351.12,  5349.49,  5351.44,
        5321.54,  5302.74,  5354.44,  5349.04,  5322.55,  5353.69,
        5366.55,  5345.69,  5295.52,  5331.35,  5343.48,  5327.36,
        5364.93,  5369.18,  5341.57,  5326.26,  5381.95,  5343.6 ,
        5372.34,  5341.09,  5341.8 ,  5319.17,  5357.89,  5366.52,
        5372.47,  5405.77,  5335.64,  5375.94,  5334.32,  5408.44,
        5345.63,  5388.27,  5407.22,  5415.23,  5402.14,  5401.65,
        5425.57,  5370.68,  5418.62,  5476.2 ,  5447.66,  5467.31,
        5444.86,  5450.44,  5525.4 ,  5489.32,  5494.43,  5457.14,
        5504.57,  5555.23,  5520.92,  5513.36,  5585.96,  5621.79,
        5558.42,  5608.05,  5596.97,  5599.98,  5583.34,  5610.35,
        5679.16,  5666.85,  5695.01,  5693.84,  5722.46,  5726.53,
        5714.61,  5722.61,  5733.16,  5699.93,  5753.52,  5754.43,
        5745.86,  5828.79,  5772.72,  5825.61,  5819.32,  5852.81,
        5876.  ,  5852.52,  5849.53,  5863.86,  5892.23,  5907.96,
        5858.39,  5942.41,  5938.36,  5935.82,  5955.2 ,  5910.05,
        5958.88,  5995.05,  5923.07,  5968.93,  5933.05,  5920.94,
        5930.83,  5993.96,  5919.47,  5956.48,  5948.48,  5966.21,
        5990.58,  5996.2 ,  5937.79,  5922.37,  5903.46,  5925.97,
        5942.13,  5878.51,  5915.93,  5895.85,  5881.16,  5835.25,
        5895.39,  5794.58,  5842.72,  5809.81,  5834.05,  5843.11,
        5771.03,  5741.2 ,  5763.68,  5738.31,  5756.64,  5686.59,
        5686.05,  5711.26,  5680.77,  5678.  ,  5670.78,  5626.55,
        5599.49,  5572.86,  5573.88,  5572.26,  5532.51,  5523.21,
        5541.77,  5528.95,  5531.11,  5542.49,  5515.9 ,  5509.62,
        5485.16,  5488.85,  5495.59,  5465.52,  5434.44,  5507.97,
        5459.17,  5421.25,  5419.23,  5416.85,  5396.44,  5410.29,
        5430.09,  5385.02,  5361.95,  5391.7 ,  5345.41,  5350.12,
        5345.22,  5370.72,  5322.03,  5348.25,  5370.73,  5338.4 ,
        5300.9 ,  5325.29,  5323.3 ,  5341.07,  5316.03,  5281.7 ,
        5333.72,  5287.52,  5355.5 ,  5313.96,  5315.16,  5314.75,
        5293.81,  5313.89,  5317.65,  5289.2 ,  5322.9 ,  5275.23,
        5273.53,  5278.15,  5291.24,  5260.07,  5290.77,  5272.02,
        5284.21,  5317.56])

z=numpy.polyfit(x,y,6)
xp = np.linspace(-1000,1000,200)
p  = np.poly1d(z)
_  = plt.plot(x, y, '.', xp, p(xp), '-')
plt.ylim(4000,7000)
plt.show()
```

**Python Output :**

```
z
    Out[35]: 
    array([ -1.93861649e-15,   1.30945729e-13,   3.97750836e-09,
            -2.32744951e-07,  -2.69634938e-03,   7.39431395e-02,
             5.93818062e+03])
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html

**Example Data :**

```
x = [-1000,  -990,  -980,  -970,  -960,  -950,  -940,  -930,  -920,
        -910,  -900,  -890,  -880,  -870,  -860,  -850,  -840,  -830,
        -820,  -810,  -800,  -790,  -780,  -770,  -760,  -750,  -740,
        -730,  -720,  -710,  -700,  -690,  -680,  -670,  -660,  -650,
        -640,  -630,  -620,  -610,  -600,  -590,  -580,  -570,  -560,
        -550,  -540,  -530,  -520,  -510,  -500,  -490,  -480,  -470,
        -460,  -450,  -440,  -430,  -420,  -410,  -400,  -390,  -380,
        -370,  -360,  -350,  -340,  -330,  -320,  -310,  -300,  -290,
        -280,  -270,  -260,  -250,  -240,  -230,  -220,  -210,  -200,
        -190,  -180,  -170,  -160,  -150,  -140,  -130,  -120,  -110,
        -100,   -90,   -80,   -70,   -60,   -50,   -40,   -30,   -20,
         -10,     0,    10,    20,    30,    40,    50,    60,    70,
          80,    90,   100,   110,   120,   130,   140,   150,   160,
         170,   180,   190,   200,   210,   220,   230,   240,   250,
         260,   270,   280,   290,   300,   310,   320,   330,   340,
         350,   360,   370,   380,   390,   400,   410,   420,   430,
         440,   450,   460,   470,   480,   490,   500,   510,   520,
         530,   540,   550,   560,   570,   580,   590,   600,   610,
         620,   630,   640,   650,   660,   670,   680,   690,   700,
         710,   720,   730,   740,   750,   760,   770,   780,   790,
         800,   810,   820,   830,   840,   850,   860,   870,   880,
         890,   900,   910,   920,   930,   940,   950,   960,   970,
         980,   990]

y = [ 5347.21,  5338.78,  5365.01,  5351.12,  5349.49,  5351.44,
        5321.54,  5302.74,  5354.44,  5349.04,  5322.55,  5353.69,
        5366.55,  5345.69,  5295.52,  5331.35,  5343.48,  5327.36,
        5364.93,  5369.18,  5341.57,  5326.26,  5381.95,  5343.6 ,
        5372.34,  5341.09,  5341.8 ,  5319.17,  5357.89,  5366.52,
        5372.47,  5405.77,  5335.64,  5375.94,  5334.32,  5408.44,
        5345.63,  5388.27,  5407.22,  5415.23,  5402.14,  5401.65,
        5425.57,  5370.68,  5418.62,  5476.2 ,  5447.66,  5467.31,
        5444.86,  5450.44,  5525.4 ,  5489.32,  5494.43,  5457.14,
        5504.57,  5555.23,  5520.92,  5513.36,  5585.96,  5621.79,
        5558.42,  5608.05,  5596.97,  5599.98,  5583.34,  5610.35,
        5679.16,  5666.85,  5695.01,  5693.84,  5722.46,  5726.53,
        5714.61,  5722.61,  5733.16,  5699.93,  5753.52,  5754.43,
        5745.86,  5828.79,  5772.72,  5825.61,  5819.32,  5852.81,
        5876.  ,  5852.52,  5849.53,  5863.86,  5892.23,  5907.96,
        5858.39,  5942.41,  5938.36,  5935.82,  5955.2 ,  5910.05,
        5958.88,  5995.05,  5923.07,  5968.93,  5933.05,  5920.94,
        5930.83,  5993.96,  5919.47,  5956.48,  5948.48,  5966.21,
        5990.58,  5996.2 ,  5937.79,  5922.37,  5903.46,  5925.97,
        5942.13,  5878.51,  5915.93,  5895.85,  5881.16,  5835.25,
        5895.39,  5794.58,  5842.72,  5809.81,  5834.05,  5843.11,
        5771.03,  5741.2 ,  5763.68,  5738.31,  5756.64,  5686.59,
        5686.05,  5711.26,  5680.77,  5678.  ,  5670.78,  5626.55,
        5599.49,  5572.86,  5573.88,  5572.26,  5532.51,  5523.21,
        5541.77,  5528.95,  5531.11,  5542.49,  5515.9 ,  5509.62,
        5485.16,  5488.85,  5495.59,  5465.52,  5434.44,  5507.97,
        5459.17,  5421.25,  5419.23,  5416.85,  5396.44,  5410.29,
        5430.09,  5385.02,  5361.95,  5391.7 ,  5345.41,  5350.12,
        5345.22,  5370.72,  5322.03,  5348.25,  5370.73,  5338.4 ,
        5300.9 ,  5325.29,  5323.3 ,  5341.07,  5316.03,  5281.7 ,
        5333.72,  5287.52,  5355.5 ,  5313.96,  5315.16,  5314.75,
        5293.81,  5313.89,  5317.65,  5289.2 ,  5322.9 ,  5275.23,
        5273.53,  5278.15,  5291.24,  5260.07,  5290.77,  5272.02,
        5284.21,  5317.56]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an orthogonal least square fit algorightm, I get:

-1.9386e-015 X^6 +  1.3095e-013 X^5 +  3.9775e-009 X^4 + -2.3274e-007 X^3 + -2.6963e-003 X^2 +  7.3943e-002 X   +  5.9382e+003

which matches the python output. Link to .rtf document for the algorithm I use, including example c code:

http://rcgldr.net/misc/opls.rtf